# List in SwiftUI Deleting and Reappearing

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

Whenever I try delete an item from the list it automatically pops back up again, however the list itself does update and delete (I checked with a print statement). When I close the app and re-open it, it has deleted, but it won't delete immediately, is there something I am missing or have not spotted that anyone else can?

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "names")!, id: \.self) { name in
                Group {
                    NavigationLink(destination: PersonView(name: name)) {
                        Text(name)
                    }
                }
            }.onDelete(perform: delete)
        }.navigationBarTitle("Names")
    }
}
```

The Delete function:

```
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    names.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(names, forKey: "names")
}
```

---

The 'names' variable is declared further up as

```
@State public var names: [String] = []
```

that updates every time a new name is added (this works). And the new name also gets added to User Defaults (this also works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `names` in your `ForEach` and load them using `onAppear` method. Something like:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                Group {
                    NavigationLink(destination: PersonView(name: name)) {
                        Text(name)
                    }
                }
            }.onDelete(perform: delete)
        }.navigationBarTitle("Names")
    }
}.onAppear{
    names = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "names") ?? []
}
```